# When to use a state

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, state-management

I have a parent component

```
<template><child></child></template> export { components: [ child] }
```

and child component

```
<template><!-- markup --></template> export { props ['id'] }
```

When I retrieve information from a resource after posting I want to be able to pass the received data from **parent** to the **child** property.

```
// parent function
then(response=>{// need to set child.id = response.data });
```

Now I tried setting the property value directly and got the warning

> [Vue warn]: Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders. Instead, use a data or computed property based on the prop's value

And I can't use emit or broadcast because I'm using Vue 2.0, $broadcast is undefined and I can't $emit to children. What would be the best way to pass the data? This value only lasts for the parent and child and does not need to be preserved or persisted.

Comment: Why can't you emit?  If you insist that you can't use events (which is the VueJS-defined way to inform the parent of data changes), you can use parent functions bound to the child that you can invoke as a callback, or you can use mixins: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html  Of course, if you need to maintain lots of application state, it may be worth using Vuex, but be aware that Vuex is most likely too much plumbing for an isolated state case.

Comment: Also, it is unclear what you are trying to accomplish.  Are you trying to pass data changes from the child to the parent?

Comment: your question is somewhat unclear what you're trying to achieve here, what's the data flow? from parent-child or child-parent or parent-child-parent?

Comment: @flyingSmurfs The work flow is from parent to child

Comment: @DavidL Sorry about not being clear. You are right about the Vuex which was why i posed the question. I'm looking into a less complex approach

Comment: @Kendall only `props` should work here if it's from parent to child or you can use `$emit` and `$on` events

Comment: @flyingSmurfs I don't think I can isn't $emit for child<-parent? I'm trying for parent -> child

Comment: You can use `$emit` to send data from `parent` to `child` and vice-versa!

Comment: @flyingSmurfs can you provide and example as I've been trying this without success

Comment: what about the doc?: http://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html